# CodeIgniter "flashdata" doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I use CodeIgniter 2.1.0, i want after insert data in database get a message like "Your information was successfully updated.". For this work i have in CI_Controller following function:

```
function myCiInser(){
... Here is my query ...
//$data: this var is result query that is true
if($data){
    $this -> session -> set_flashdata('message', 'Your information was successfully updated.');
    redirect('url/myurl');
            }
}
```

And i have in view as:

```
<?php
$message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    if($message){
        echo '<div id="error_text">' . $message . '</div>';
    }
//I test this : "echo $message;" but don't give output
?>
```

But i don't give message in view but `redirect` is done and work true. and in database in table `ci_sessions` column `user_data` i have this:

> a:2:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:19:"flash:new:message";s:42:"Your
>   information was successfully updated.";}

How can fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I had the following error (i use from chorme and by Ctrl+Shift+j i get this alert):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

And i fix it (Now i do not have the error) but still is same problem in display message. what do i do?

Comment: Is it a typo, but you assign the flashdata to $message_p, but echo $message ?

Comment: No, please see again my post.

Comment: Any solution? I see flashdata do not work when using session with database.

Comment: thank you for your UPDATE. after removing some 404 (not found) items from view, my flashdata is working normally. i think that 404 will count as one server request.

Comment: hi this is old question but how u solved this probleam i also got this probleam

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Codeigniter [Session Class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), regarding **Flashdata** we can read:

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared.

Your problem might be that when you redirect, the process takes more than one request, clearing your flashdata.

To see if that's the case, just add the following code to the constructor of the controller you are redirecting to:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
```

This will keep the flashdata for another server request, allowing it to be used afterwards.

Comment: I test `keep_flashdata` but doesn't work, still is same problem. What is difference between `keep_flashdata` and `flashdata` ?

Comment: The keep_flashdata() method is not suposed to replace flashdata(). keep_flashdata() preserves a flashdata variable through an additional request. You should read the documentation on the link that I posted.

Comment: Is this necessary to redirect the page to keep flash data.
My problem is that first time flash data works fine but when I refresh the page the flash data message is cleared.

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan Well, that's the whole point of flash data. As soon as you read it in the first request, it's cleared in the next one. If you need to keep the data regardless of how many requests you do, use the default session methods, not the flash one.

Comment: Actually I want to carry the flashdata up to two requests after that I want that this session value should be cleared. On first request its working good but on the second the is cleared although I've used the keep_flashdata command.

Comment: I bet the request you think is second, is actually the third and you lost the data by that point.

Answer (score 12):

I had that problem too. I don't remember where I saw but here's my solution.

```
redirect('url/myurl','refresh');
```

CodeIgniter didn't treated redirect as another request. So flashdata wasn't set in the redirect, but it was on the next page I loaded.

Comment: Yeap, removing the refresh seems to fix a 'refresh' bug in FF. All browsers acknowledge the redirect without 'refresh'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is working for me - redirect('url/myurl','refresh');

Answer (score 3):

// Set flash data in our controller file

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('sessionkey', 'Value');
```

// After that we need to used redirect function

```
redirect("admin/signup");
```

// Get Flash data on view

```
$this->session->flashdata('sessionkey');
```

Comment: @AlphaMale will you please specify, your problem.

Comment: problem is that i was using same code for my flash messages. but all of sudden they are not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Using sessions with database has caused me issues at times. I recommend setting `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;` in the *config.php* and see if the flashdata works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use database for the sessions, but you have to set the config items:

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

In that way the session flashdata will work again

Comment: Bingo, that was my problem. This got to be a bug, I mean we can't use cookies in a safe way and flashdata at same time? Someone that uses Laravel can give us an input?

Answer (score 1):

Except one page, I am able to display/pass values using session. I tried using the `var_dump($this->session)` and I get:

```
["flash:old:Array"]=> bool(false)
["flash:new:message"]=> string(10) "My Message"
```

I have tried echoing the flash data within the page without redirecting just after setting the data, but the result was same. I recommend to trim down the code, and try to set session in other pages. If the problem persists check your `var_dump`. This might not be the solution, but I think it can help.

> **UPDATE** : trimming down spaces and newlines within the text
>   worked. I was passing 2 long sentences with empty line breaks and spaces.

```
if (0) //Assume this condition is false
{   
    $this->load->view('error_page');
    // Generate validation error
}
else
{
    //Show success message
    $data = array(
                'message' => 'My message'
                           );
    $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
    $this->session->keep_flashdata($data);                      
    echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
    //echo var_dump($this->session);
    //redirect(base_url().'success_page');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After checking the code I have found, that I am calling `$this->session->sess_destroy();`, which causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

404 (not found) count as 1 server request. it will remove your flashdata.

Answer (score 0):

As I am observing about codeigniter flashdata.
When I use it in second request using codeigniter redirect() method it is working fine in mozila but in the case of chrome it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late but I was having this problem and I couldn't believe that in my case the solution was very easy

just replace

```
$this->session->flashdata('message');
```

to

```
print_r($this->session->flashdata('message'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Chrome developer console open and flashdata was removed. After closing it and retrying it works. 
Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I use this for flash data and it's easy to use.
first, need to you have creat session and then in your controllers' method use this just before where you want to redirect your page.

On Controller after creating a session and don't forget to load session and url library.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Oops. This email id already exist.' );
redirect("You Mehod or page");
```

In this case, you no need to go to your particular view page to add extra php code.

And on footer.php in view past this script code

```
<!-- Code for flashdata toaster -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')){ ?>
        toastr.success("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>");
    <?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){  ?>
        toastr.error("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>");
    <?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('warning')){  ?>
        toastr.warning("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning'); ?>");
    <?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('info')){  ?>
        toastr.info("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>");
    <?php } ?>
</script>
<!-- End of flashdata script -->
```

Good luck and hope it will help for your problem.