# CodeIgniter flashdata

Tags: codeigniter

I'm running into a problem I just can't seem to fix. I'm working on kind of a CMS kind of thing. And one of the functions is making image slideshows.

In one controller, I check if a slideshow with a certain ID exists, and if it exists, it should take the data and work with it, otherwise, set an error message (CodeIgniter flashdata) and redirect to the homepage.

The code I use for this is the following:

```
if($this->Mslideshow->slideshowExists($showid) === FALSE){
    echo 'I\'m getting here';
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$showid);
    redirect('admin/index','refresh');
}else{
    echo 'Slideshow exists';
}
```

And the code of the `slideshowExists()` function is:

```
public function slideshowExists($showid)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$showid)
             ->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get('slideshows');

    if($query->num_rows() < 1){
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->currentquery = $query;

    return TRUE;
}
```

And the problem is this, very strange actually. If the result I get back is `FALSE`, everything goes as planned. Error message gets set and redirect goes to 'admin/index'.
But if what I get back is TRUE, then the stange thing happens. I do get an `echo` with 'Slideshow exists', but I also get the error message.

I've tried everything, deleted cookies. Reset all sessions etc.

And even stranger is that when I tried to put the `$showid` I use to check into the error message, all of a sudden `$showid` is ' img '. While everywhere else is '1' or '2'...

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

=====EDIT=====

I tried to edit the code and simplify it. Right now I have this code in my Controller:

```
public function slideshow($showid){
$query = $this->db->where('id',$showid)->get('slideshows');
if($query->num_rows() < 1){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Slideshow doesn\'t exist.');
    redirect('admin/index','refresh');
}

$data['page'] = 'slideshow';
$data['title'] = 'Slideshows';
$this->scripts->load_scripts(array());
$this->scripts->load_functions(array());
$this->load->view('admin/dashboard_template.php',$data);
}
```

When I run this with a `$showid`, that doesn't exist, I get the error message after being redirected to 'admin/index'. When I use a `$showid` that does exist, I do get the error, but no redirect but just the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to read your flash data in your view:

```
$error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
var_dump($error);
```

or in your Controller:

```
$error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
if(isset($error)) {
     var_dump($error);
}
```

Also you can read this question: [CodeIgniter "flashdata" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the flash data by following way

```
$error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
if($error)
{
echo $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if($this->session->flashdata('msg') != "")
```

This works for me.