# Why can’t I get my Flashdata for my next server request in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I’ve been trying to figure out how to use those flashdatas.
I remember having difficulties last time, and this time again, it seems that I forget something.

So basically, I’m trying to set up a flasherror somewhere :

```
if(!$this->paypal_pro->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['ACK']))
  {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  
           array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['ERRORS']));
       redirect('main/form');
  }
```

And in my main/form I got :

```
function Form()
 {
// Process validation form
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {
      //IF the validation process hasn't been run or there are validation errors
       $this->parser->parse('template/template', $data);
 }
```

And in that view, I’m trying to get that flashError :

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
  <div class='flashError'>
 <?php  
  $flashError=$this->session->flashdata('flashError');
  foreach( $flashError['Errors'] as $Error) {
     echo $Error['L_SHORTMESSAGE'].' ('.$Error['L_ERRORCODE'].'):';
     echo '<br/>';
     echo $Error['L_LONGMESSAGE'];
  }
 ?>
  </div>
 <?php endif?>
```

I don’t have anything in that variable, and when I try to var_dump it, It returns me false.

Can someone explain me how to use it despite the official documentation saying “will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared”

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Codeigniters documentation:

> If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an
>   additional request, you can do so using the keep_flashdata() function.

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

**UPDATE:**

Problem seems to be here:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  
           array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['ERRORS']));
```

Try this one:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata(array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['ERRORS']));
```

Comment: yep but what do you want me to keep if there is nothing ? :p
I mean if I do that, It will keep my flash data, yes, but my flashdata is already null, when I do the redirect, it seems to disappear ..

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing

```
if($this->session->flashdata('flashError'))
```

You are actually removing the `flashError` item, as it has been read.

What you need to do, is as you have a little further down, assign it to a variable and then do your checks.

Comment: wow I'm surprise, You mean, as soon as I read it once it disappears ? But wait, I did var_dump and print_r in the controller, before the view, and there was already nothing .. as soon as I leave the first function (first part of the code I gave) the flashdata seems to be gone..

Comment: Yup, although I'm "sure" it's meant to disappear after the next "request". Odd huh ;)