# Codeigniter Flashdata Not displaying on web server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

My codeigniter application works perfectly on localhost. What should happen is that when a form gets sent correctly a success flash message is returned.

Like I said this works perfectly on my localhost but if I upload the site, it just doesn't populate the message. In my contact form for example, the email gets sent but no flash message. Both of these steps are located in the same block of code however.

I have contacted my host but they said that it can't be a setting on the server.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Regards.

Comment: you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if it's a similar problem that happened with me but in my case, it turned out that my sessions (hence flashdata) were being destroyed before my script could output them.

Check to make sure nothing is destroying or overwriting your flashdata before it reaches the output.

**Note:**
By the way, if you're using CodeIgniter's feature where you can use the database itself to store sessions, make sure all the database settings are correct. Check if the sessions table is actually available (ci_sessions by default). It's an easy mistake to make when moving from a localhost environment.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
**Check:** Saving Session Data to a Database

Comment: Hi Mahmoud. I fixed the problem. I had a closing php tag in my one layout file which cause a header already sent problem. Only figured this out after changing environment back to development on the live server. Thank you very much for your feedback!