# flashdata codeigniter is not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm following a tutorial from youtube, but I'm having a problem in case of **flashdata**. It's not showing up while in the tutorial I'm following it's running well. Here's the code

```
function create(){

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->module('site_security');
    $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();

    $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $submit = $this->input->post('submit', TRUE);

    if ($submit == "Submit"){
        //Process the form
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_title', 'Item Title', 'required|max_length[240]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_price', 'Item Price', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('was_price', 'Was Price ', 'numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_description', 'Item Description', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            //get the variables
            $data = $this->fetch_data_from_post();

            if (is_numeric($update_id)){
                //update the item details
                $this->_update($update_id, $data);
                $flash_msg      = "The item details were successfully updated.";
                $value          = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'.$flash_msg.'</div>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('item', $value);
                redirect('store_items/create/'.$update_id);
            }else{
                //insert a new file
                $this->_insert($data);
                $update_id      = $this->get_max();//get the ID of the new item
                $flash_msg      = "The item was successfully added.";
                $value          = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'.$flash_msg.'</div>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('item', $value);
                redirect('store_items/create/'.$update_id);
            }
        }
    }

    if ((is_numeric($update_id)) && ($submit != "Submit")){
        $data = $this->fetch_data_from_db($update_id);
    }else{
        $data = $this->fetch_data_from_post();
    }

    if (!is_numeric($update_id)){
        $data['headline'] = "Add New Item";
    }else{
        $data['headline'] = "Update Item Details";
    }

    $data['update_id']      = $update_id;
    $data['flash']          = $this->session->flashdata('item');
    $data['view_module']    = "store_items";
    $data['view_file']      = "create";
    $this->load->module('templates');
    $this->templates->admin($data);
}
```

in view, I just echo $flash. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: flash data works once the page gets reloaded only

Comment: as you're passing `$data['flash']` just pass string and in respective view, if its not empty show the value

Comment: flashdata works only to the next page request. Why don't you use tempdata in your case?

Comment: so, how should the code be? @DeadManAlive

Comment: @MuhammadAbdurrouf  what this code does `$this->templates->admin` ??

Comment: @DeadManAlive well, I'm using HMVC. It is calling templates module -> view -> admin.php. Theres nothing wrong with that. The only problem is that the flashdata doesnt show up

Comment: show us how you access this in your view

Comment: @DeadManAlive <?php
if (isset($flash)){
    echo $flash;
} ?>

Comment: how you print `view_file` in your view ?

Comment: @DeadManAlive sorry if this will bother you, but can I have your email? so we can chat more intensively, or I will be able to send you my code. Or you can send me email first. here it is abdrouf8@gmail.com

Comment: Does the profiler show the expected data in your session? Can you echo the $data['flash'] value in the controller and see it is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to pass **$data['flash']** variable.

You can call the variable directly from the view. e.g. `echo $this->session->flashdata('item')`

Comment: Try This:

if($this->session->flashdata('item')):
          echo $this->session->flashdata('item');
endif;

Comment: Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

you can  use this code in view page

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

Comment: From the Codeigniter Session Class documentation, regarding Flashdata we can read:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work

Comment: You should try it your own and then you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got the answer. It is a problem with my current CI version. So I just upgraded to the latest one, and it works fine. Or actually I could use my current CI version still, but I need to downgrade my PHP version. Thats all. Btw, thanks alot to people who already tried to help me here.